# APK Keep Stopped after install in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

please help me solution, after run apk in emulator, apps has stopped working, and i check in logcat, i have error in InputAddress.java:34.

this my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input);

    inputLayoutAddress = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_address);
    inputAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_address);
    inputAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                inputAddress.setSelection(inputAddress.getText().length());
            }
        }
    });
    btnLanjut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lanjut);
    inputAddress.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputAddress));
    btnLanjut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            submitForm();
        }
    });

    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Peringatan")
                .setMessage("Tidak ada koneksi")
                .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                })
                .show();
```

}

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  And tell us which one is line 34.

Comment: Remove the line `System.exit(0)` in the click listener of dialog.

Comment: Is line 34, setContentView(R.layout.input);

Comment: I try remove System.exit(0), not solved problem